# NumPy/PyTorch slicing using an array of indices from an argmax call

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, slice, numpy-slicing

I have the following `tensors / ndarrays` I am operating with.

`a_intents` of shape `(b, n_i)` - Scalar at position `ij` is the activation of intent `j` for the `i-th` element in the batch.

`u_intents` of shape `(b, n_i, d_m)` - Vector of dimension `d_m` at index `ij` is the pose vector of intent `j` for the `i-th` element in the batch.

I want to get the index of the intent with the biggest activation scalar, and I do:

```
 max_activations = argmax(a_intents, dim=-1, keepdim=False)
```

Now, using those indices, I want to get the corresponding vectors in `u_intents`.

```
max_activation_poses = u_intents[?, ?,:]
```

How do I use `max_activations` to indicate only those indices on `dim 1`? My intuition tells me I will end with an incorrect shape if I do

```
[:, max_activations, :]
```

The shape I am trying to get is `(b, d_m)` - The vector with the same index as the `highest activation`, for each element in the batch.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at ```np.take_along_axis``` It is often used in conjunction with functions that return indices, like ```argmax```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy if you treat the `u_intents` vector as 2-dimensional, and offset each argmax index by its batch index times the number of elements.

```
# dummy values for demonstration
>>> b, n_i, d_m = 2, 3, 5
>>> a_intents = torch.rand(b, n_i)
>>> a_intents
tensor([[0.1733, 0.9965, 0.4790],
        [0.6056, 0.4040, 0.0236]])
>>> u_intents = torch.rand(b, n_i, d_m)
>>> u_intents
tensor([[[0.3301, 0.8153, 0.1356, 0.6623, 0.4385],
         [0.1902, 0.1748, 0.4131, 0.3887, 0.5363],
         [0.1211, 0.5773, 0.2405, 0.6313, 0.2064]],
        [[0.2592, 0.5127, 0.7301, 0.8883, 0.5665],
         [0.2767, 0.6545, 0.7595, 0.2677, 0.5163],
         [0.8158, 0.4940, 0.0492, 0.0911, 0.0465]]])
# add to each index the batch start
>>> max_activations = a_intents.argmax(dim=-1) + torch.arange(0, b*n_i, step=n_i)
# elements 1 and 3 of 0..5
>>> max_activations
tensor([1, 3])   
>>> poses = u_intents.view(b*n_i, d_m).index_select(0, max_activations)
# tensor of shape (b, d_m) correctly indexing the maxima.
>>> poses
tensor([[0.1902, 0.1748, 0.4131, 0.3887, 0.5363],
        [0.2592, 0.5127, 0.7301, 0.8883, 0.5665]])
```

Comment: Does the job. I have recently found out the equivalent of np.take_along_axis, which is torch.gather, and I am trying to write a solution that uses that, as it looks more elegant. Thank you for the effort, regardless, really appreciated! :D